# Derived algebra of a lie algebra contained in an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  Assume $\mathfrak{i}$ is an ideal with $\mathfrak{g/i}$ abelian. Then the derived algebra $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq \mathfrak{i}$.  I don't see why this is true.  I am new to Lie algebras and am probably missing something obvious.  I would appreciate if someone could show me why.  Thanks!

Comment: Take any two elements $x$ and $y$. Then in the quotient, $[x,y] = 0$ and hence $[x,y]\in i$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So if $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, then $0+\mathfrak{i}=[X+\mathfrak{i},Y+\mathfrak{i}]=[X,Y]+\mathfrak{i}$ implying $[X,Y]\ \in \mathfrak{i}$ with first equal sign due to abelian and second equal by deifnitition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft please formulate your comment as an answer so I can give you credit. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, we can denote by $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ their images in $\mathfrak{g}/i$. Since the quotient is abelian, we have $[\bar{x},\bar{y}] = 0$, which means that $[x,y]\in i$, and hence that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq i$.